# Twitter Social login in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, twitter-oauth, python-social-auth

I want to add login with Twitter option in my Django application.
Can you please provide me some basic intro, detailed description or recommend me some books to read. Any tutorial would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) for twitter login or [Django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for many social authentication services including twitter

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t find an answer online, start by searching for connected topics: in this case for example how to use the standard login system provided, how to work with authorization etc.

In this case, I ended up googling “Facebook twitter login Django” and found several good resources. Try that!

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way would be to use [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django)